# How to rewrite part of the url with .htaccess?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess

I'm not that good with .htaccess, so I wonder, how can I rewrite default 'node' part of the url to an 'article' for example, so that server will output 'article/1' instead of 'node/1'. I need this to be done on a server side, so with the use of .htaccess only. Any guess?

Comment: Pathauto will change the URL on the server side as well, as it is a PHP module that is executed on the server. It looks like the easiest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) will allow you to set customised paths like this in Drupal. It's a must-have for Drupal (should be in Core, really). Just install and configure via the easy web-interface and you'll be all set.

You can even have different patterns for different node types. As an example, if you had 'page' and 'news' content types, your pages could have URLs like `http://example.com/about-us` while your news items could have urls like `http://example.com/news/2009/05/28/news-post-title`.

Comment: A downvote? This is the only answer that'll get Drupal to output links to a custom URL scheme instead of `node/1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is that you don't understand what `mod_rewrite` (which is what's doing the work you want, not `.htaccess`) does.  It doesn't change the HTML you're outputting; it changes how the server interprets incoming URL requests.

So if your Drupal install understands `node/1` and you want people to see `article/1`, first you need to modify the HTML output so it embeds links to `article/1`.  Then you rewrite from `article/1` to `node/1` like so, in a `.htaccess` or Apache config file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule article/ node/ [NS]
```